# My "spring boot application' cant be accessed but cpu and heap usage is normal

Tags: linux, spring-boot, kubernetes

Background:

I have  a kubernates cluster in my cloud server,And i deployed  spring boot application as a pod .Everything is ok before 2 week , but my application unexpectedly could not be accessed on Ferb 22.

I used command `"kubectl exec -it  <pod> sh "`,`curl 127.0.0.1:<port>` in pods  but  no response .I saw my application logs but cant found error about this issue.I try to restart my applications ,but the same issue occur after two days.

I have no idea with this issues.Can any one help me ?

When everything ok ,i can call `127.0.0.1:18890` and have response immediately ,once issues happend  it will be  requested timeout .Only this  kubernates service have this question ,others seems normal

[image]

Comment: Is 127.0.0.1 really the correct IP address?

Comment: Your application may not be starting and it might be failing again and again and restarting itself. 
Please check the logs carefully and also check that in your prod env you have enabled console log appender, So that your logs will not be destroyed once your application restart and you can able to see all the logs.

Comment: can you add more details? cloud? configuration, logs, what you did in addition to reboot? Edit question, otherwise it would be closed

Comment: My application running correct  at first ,but it will be dead ( request time out  ) within a few days . I check my log carefully but find nothing ,no destroyed log ,no error logs .

Comment: @Vitalii What configuration do you want kubernates spring cluod? I dont know  where is the problem .

Comment: what cloud you use? can you share info about your service, current endpoints info

Comment: Finally，i found the answer about this question.My application request third party interface but i don't set timeout .third party interface is not stable ,so there are many unclosed connection in my application.I guess it blocked application's thread made  our application down .After i set timeout config ,no same issues happened.